# SQL renaming - Renaming a column from an input from another column

Tags: sql, join

Is there way to rename a column from a name that was inputed into another column?

Currently I have a piece of code that that are join together and I'm writing the final SELECT statement that will display the columns I want. The three columns I want displaying is

```
SELECT answer1 AS answer_q1,
       answer2 AS answer_q2,
       COUNT(distinct(user)) AS response_count
```

In the previous lines of code I have inputed questions where it looks like question = 'What is your name?' just for instance. Is there a way to rename answer 1 as that question instead with something like:

```
SELECT answer1 AS q1.question
```

Comment: Just a note, `DISTINCT` is not a function. Simply write `count(distinct user_id) AS response_count` to make your code clearer.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

you should use dynamic query.I can help more if you describe your tables and columns more.and write example of their data.questions are in another table or get from input variable?

Comment: the question(for example :'Do you have active checking?') is got from input? is it a variable? clearly can we write : declare @q varchar(max) and then set it with input?

Comment: sorry.your issue is not clear.could you send a sample of result you want? an image from the ideal result

Comment: I added the image, where it says Q1 if its possible to make it labeled as the question gotten from c.question="Do you have active checking?", but sometimes different questions will be inputed into that part

Answer (score 0):

if I got your mean ,in sql server you can write:

```
declare @q1 varchar(500)
declare @q2 varchar(500)
declare @sql varchar(max) =
'select q1.answer as '+@q1+' ,q2.answer as '+@q2+' ,q1.cnt+q2.cnt as count
from
  (SELECT b.answer ,count(discount(user_id)) cnt
  FROM user_offer_question_answer a    
  JOIN offer_question_answer b ON a.offer_question_id= b.offer_question_id    AND 
  a.offer_question_answer_id=b.id    
  JOIN question c ON a.offer_question_id=c.id  
  group by b.answer
  WHERE c.question='+@q1+') q1
cross join
  (SELECT b.answer ,count(discount(user_id)) cnt
  FROM user_offer_question_answer a    
  JOIN offer_question_answer b ON a.offer_question_id= b.offer_question_id    AND 
  a.offer_question_answer_id=b.id    
  JOIN question c ON a.offer_question_id=c.id  
  group by b.answer,c.question
  WHERE c.question='+@q2+')q2'
exec @sql
```

Comment: after further looking into it, it seems snowflake doesn't support dynamic sql, so error statement keeps occurring saying unexpected @q1 at line 1